# Is screen recording feature supported in PWA for mobile?

Tags: android, ios, web, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have a requirement to develop an app whose requirement is to record the screen of mobile. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture, we can't record mobile screen. Since, I am native app developer, just wanted to confirm whether screen recording functionality can be achieved by PWA?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry it's not available on Chrome on Android.